# Android Studio InflateException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to program a simple GUI Game of Life in Android Studio, but whenever I try to run it, the app closes unexpectedly. The Android Monitor keeps throwing out an InflateException. I've checked a lot of posts on this website about InflateException, but none of them have helped my situation yet.

API - 25

This is the error:

```
11-28 16:41:30.292 18444-18444/com.cs3340.gameoflife E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.cs3340.gameoflife, PID: 18444
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cs3340.gameoflife/com.cs3340.gameoflife.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.cs3340.gameoflife.GameView
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.cs3340.gameoflife.GameView
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.cs3340.gameoflife.GameView
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                                                                       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                                       at com.cs3340.gameoflife.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And this is the xml file it is referring to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.cs3340.gameoflife.GameView
    android:id="@+id/gameView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>"
```

And this is the View itself:

```
package com.cs3340.gameoflife;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * GameView is used to draw a single generation of the Game of Life
 */
public class GameView extends View {

/**
 * Variables used to calculate the size of the cells of the grid
 */
private static final int CELL_SIZE = 40;
private static final int HEIGHT = GameGlobal.getViewportHeight() / CELL_SIZE;
private static final int WIDTH = GameGlobal.getViewportWidth() / CELL_SIZE;

/**
 * Color of the grid
 */
private Paint background = new Paint();

/**
 * Color of the cells
 */
private Paint cellColor = new Paint();

/**
 * This represents the Cell Grid
 */
private int [][] grid;

/**
 * Flag to check if the game is running and prevent any changes to the grid
 */
private static boolean isRunning = false;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context
 */
public GameView(Context context){
    super(context);
    init();
}

/**
 * Constructor helper method, initializes the varibales
 */
private void init(){
    cellColor.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    background.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    initGrid();
}

/**
 * Helper method creates the grid and initializes all cells to 0, ie "Dead"
 */
private void initGrid(){
    grid = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Draws the grid to the screen and sets the color
 * @param canvas
 */
public void gameViewDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawRect((float) 0, (float) 0, (float) getWidth(),
            (float) getHeight(), background);
}

/**
 * This class handles the touch screen event of pressing on a cell
 * @param event
 */
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x = (int) event.getX() / CELL_SIZE;
    int y = (int) event.getY() / CELL_SIZE;

    //if the cell is dead, make it alive and vice-versa
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(grid[y][x] == 0){
                grid[y][x] = 1;
            }
            else{
                grid[y][x] = 0;
            }
        break;
    }
    //redraws the view thread
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Mutator method for isRunning
 * @param running Boolean to set if the game is running or not
 */
public void setIsRunning(boolean running){
    isRunning = running;
}

/**
 * Accessor method to return the cell grid
 * @return Game of Life cell grid
 */
public int[][] getGrid(){
    return grid;
}

/**
 * Runs the game as an infinite loop
 */
public void gameLoop(){

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        /**
         * Takes a 3x3 array around the current cell we are going to test for the next gen value
         * @param squared 3x3 array around current cell
         * @return nextGeneration state of the cell
         */
        public int nextGeneration(int[][] squared){
            //value of the middle cell, ie, the cell we are testing for next gen
            int currentGen = squared[1][1];

            /**
             * calculates how many live cells are in the 3x3 array
             */
            int alive = 0;

            if(currentGen == 1){
                alive--; //removes 1 from the possible number of alive cells because we need only the surrounding cells
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    if(squared[i][j] == 1){
                        alive++;
                    }
                }

            }
            /**
             * Applies the default Conways Game of Life rules:
             * Alive Cell= > less than 2 or more than 3 live neighbours = dead
             *             > 2 or 3 live neighbours = alive
             *
             * Dead Cell= > Exactly 3 live neighbours = alive
             *            > Else = dead
             */
            if(currentGen == 1){
                if(alive < 2 || alive > 3){
                    return 0;
                } else{
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if(currentGen == 0){
                if(alive == 3){
                    return 1;
                } else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
             //safety, never actually used
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public void run(){
            //initializing the array to be used in nextGeneration()
            int[][] squared = new int [3][3];

            /**
             * While the game is running
             */
            while(isRunning){
                //temporary array to hold the new generation
                int[][] nextGen = new int[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

                //This inserts every possible 3x3 grid from the original cell grid to be tested for the next generation values
                //This loop also takes into account wrapping
                for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; i < WIDTH; j++){

                        // row 1
                        if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[0][0] = grid[i - 1][j - 1];
                        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[0][0] = grid[HEIGHT - 1][j - 1];
                        else if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 < 0)
                            squared[0][0] = grid[j - 1][WIDTH - 1];
                        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j - 1 < 0)
                            squared[0][0] = grid[HEIGHT - 1][WIDTH - 1];


                        if (i - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[0][1] = grid[i - 1][j];
                        else
                            squared[0][1] = grid[HEIGHT - 1][j];


                        if (i - 1 >= 0 && j < WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[0][2] = grid[i - 1][j + 1];
                        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j < WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[0][2] = grid[HEIGHT - 1][j + 1];
                        else if (i - 1 >= 0 && j >= WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[0][2] = grid[i - 1][0];
                        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j >= WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[0][2] = grid[HEIGHT - 1][0];

                        // row 2
                        if (j - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[1][0] = grid[i][j - 1];
                        else
                            squared[1][0] = grid[i][WIDTH - 1];


                        squared[1][1] = grid[i][j];


                        if (j < WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[1][2] = grid[i][j + 1];
                        else
                            squared[1][2] = grid[i][0];

                        // row 3
                        if (i < HEIGHT - 1 && j - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[2][0] = grid[i + 1][j - 1];
                        else if (i >= HEIGHT - 1 && j - 1 >= 0)
                            squared[2][0] = grid[0][j - 1];
                        else if (i < HEIGHT - 1 && j - 1 < 0)
                            squared[2][0] = grid[i + 1][WIDTH - 1];
                        else if (i >= HEIGHT - 1 && j - 1 < 0)
                            squared[2][0] = grid[0][WIDTH - 1];


                        if (i < HEIGHT - 1)
                            squared[2][1] = grid[i + 1][j];
                        else
                            squared[2][1] = grid[0][j];


                        if (i < HEIGHT - 1 && j < WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[2][2] = grid[i + 1][j + 1];
                        else if (i >= HEIGHT - 1 && j < WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[2][2] = grid[0][j + 1];
                        else if (i < HEIGHT - 1 && j >= WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[2][2] = grid[i + 1][0];
                        else if (i >= HEIGHT - 1 && j >= WIDTH - 1)
                            squared[2][2] = grid[0][0];


                        nextGen[i][j] = nextGeneration(squared);

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }).start();


    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GameView` needs a two-argument constructor, as this is the constructor used by `LayoutInflater` to build view hierarchies from XML.

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
```